# Implementing setState causes Infinite Loop Flutter

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm having state issue. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

So I'm initially setting the items of a Flutter drop-downmenu to a list, which we'll call List l  And it's value too, which will call variable v.

Then at the beginning of the parent widget, before build, I call a method which gets some information from the sqlflite database. And when it returns, I create a new List of drop-downmenuItem and implement the new state. 
I set List l to the newly created and the value to the first value of the first item of the List, so that the drop-downmenu re-renders.

This seems to be working fine, except that the method which gets info from the database keeps getting called which causes an infinite loop. And freezes my app. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

```
    // Declaring variables
    List<DropdownMenuItem> _classList;

    String _chosenClass;


    initState:

    @override

    void initState() {

     _classList = [DropdownMenuItem(

       child: Text("Choose Class"),

       value: null,)];

     _chosenClass = _classList.first.value;

     super.initState();

    }


    // Get info from sqlflite database: 

    getClassesToDisplay() {

     debugPrint("Works");

     getDatabaseInstances(tableClass, [className]).then((classNames){

       if(classNames.length > 0){

         List<DropdownMenuItem> tempList =[];

         classNames.forEach((classArg){

           tempList.add(

               DropdownMenuItem(

                 child: Text(classArg[className]),

                 value: classArg[className],

               )

           );

         });

         debugPrint("TEMPLIST: ${tempList}");

         setState(() {

           _classList = tempList;

           _chosenClass = tempList.first.value;

         });

       }


     });


    }


    // Build:

    @override

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     getClassesToDisplay();

     debugPrint("BLAHHHH");

     return new Scaffold(

       appBar: new AppBar(

         title: new Text("Your Classes"),

       ),

       body: Column(

         children: <Widget>[

           Container(

             margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 10.0),

             child: raisedButtonMaker("Tap to add a class", (){

               Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/add_seek');

             }, Theme.of(context).primaryColor, context)

           ,),

           DropdownButton(

             value: _chosenClass, //value of currently picked item

             items: _classList,

             onChanged: (value){ //update value of dropDown to what was just chosen

               setState(() {

                 _chosenClass = value;

               });

             },

           ),

         ],

       ),

     );

    }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getClassesToDisplay()` calls `setState()` with a delay (`then`) which causes `build()` to be run, which calls `getClassesToDisplay()` - simple endless loop.

Remove `getClassesToDisplay()` from `build()` and call it from `initState()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. So setState always re-builds the whole parent widget? I thought it only rebuilds the specific part where the state was changed--like just the dropDownMenu in this example.

Comment: `setState()` is a method of the widget. If you call it, this widget will be rebuilt. The code in your question is missing the widget class name, with that it would be easier to point to ;-) It's the widget that contains all the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Now I know exactly when the build method is executed, which will help solve so many problems. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. What if I want the widget to update everytime I navigate to the screen the widget is on. When I move getClassesToDisplay() to initState, the widget is only rendered when it is first inserted into the tree. However, I need to update the DropdownButton to reflect some value based on some other page. I think this is the problem I was trying to avoid in the first place! :)